# Perform javascript operations through child DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to loop through all containers with a given class (`.war`) and being able to perform the comparation between two child elements and adding a different class to each one of them (winner / loser).

Optimizing the DOM, being able to remove `.score a` / `.score b` and leave it all with `.score` will be awesome if possible.

I tried iterating with child elements with javascript and jquery, with no results.

```js
var scoreA = document.getElementsByClassName("score a")[0];
var scoreB = document.getElementsByClassName("score b")[0];

if (scoreA > scoreB) {
  scoreA.classList.add("win");
  scoreB.classList.add("lose");
} else {
  scoreA.classList.add("lose");
  scoreB.classList.add("win");
}
```

```css
.team { padding: 8px 10px; display: inline-block;}.team:nth-child(1) .score { text-align: right; display: block;}.team:nth-child(2) { text-align: right;}.team:nth-child(2) .score { text-align: left; display: block;}.war { display: inline-block; background-color: #F4F5F7; border-radius: 4px; position: relative; margin: 2px 0;}.score { border-radius: 4px; padding: 1px 5px;}.score.lose { background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);}.score.win { background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .15);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score a">4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score b">2</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score a">8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score b">5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score a">2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score b">3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you need to select all the `.war` elements, which you can achieve with `querySelectorAll()`, then loop through them and compare the scores of the child elements.

Also note that you need to convert the string scores to integers, otherwise `2` would be considered higher than `12`. Try this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.war').forEach(function(war) {
  var scoreA = war.getElementsByClassName("score a")[0];
  var scoreB = war.getElementsByClassName("score b")[0];

  if (parseInt(scoreA.innerText, 10) > parseInt(scoreB.innerText, 10)) {
    scoreA.classList.add("win");
    scoreB.classList.add("lose");
  } else {
    scoreA.classList.add("lose");
    scoreB.classList.add("win");
  }
});
```

```css
.team {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.team:nth-child(1) .score {
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
}

.team:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: right;
}

.team:nth-child(2) .score {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}

.war {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #F4F5F7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.score {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}

.score.lose {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
}

.score.win {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .15);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score a">12</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score b">2</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score a">8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score b">5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score a">2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score b">3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you'd prefer to do this without explicitly referencing the `.score.a` and `.score.b` elements, then you could use `reduce` to get the index of the highest score and then apply the classes based on that index:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.war').forEach(function(war) {
  var scores = Array.from(war.getElementsByClassName("score"));
  var winIndex = scores.reduce((iMax, x, i, arr) => parseInt(x.innerText, 10) > parseInt(arr[iMax].innerText, 10) ? i : iMax, 0);      
  scores.forEach((score, i) => score.classList.add(winIndex == i ? 'win' : 'lose'));
});
```

```css
.team {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.team:nth-child(1) .score {
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
}

.team:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: right;
}

.team:nth-child(2) .score {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}

.war {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #F4F5F7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.score {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}

.score.lose {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
}

.score.win {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .15);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score a">4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score b">2</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score a">8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score b">5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score a">2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score b">3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, easy fix, appreciate it. And a way to loop through the childs so I can remove those auxiliary class ? `.a` and `.b`.

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer to show one possible solution for that. It's a little ugly though, as it requires two loops.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @Rory McCrossan, was wondering how your inline conditional `winIndex == i ? 'win' : 'lose'` would be with a third statement 'draw' (a == b), thanks !

Comment: To cater for draws you'd need to restructure the logic quite a bit, not just the ternary. I'd suggest starting a new question about it if you have issues.

Comment: As you mentioned, I have opened a new question for this new alternative, if you feel like passing by, I'll leave it to you: [new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870604/apply-different-class-to-child-dom-elements-depending-on-their-value/52871102). Thanks again :)