# Apply different class to child DOM elements depending on their value

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757101/perform-javascript-operations-through-child-dom-elements).

We got a structure like the one below, depending on the value of the element with class `score` we add a class `win` or `lose`.

```
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score">8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score">5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score">12</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score">25</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score">57</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score">57</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

User Rory McCrossan provided a working solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/52757164/4236048

```
document.querySelectorAll('.war').forEach(function(war) {
  var scores = Array.from(war.getElementsByClassName("score"));
  var winIndex = scores.reduce((iMax, x, i, arr) => parseInt(x.innerText, 10) > parseInt(arr[iMax].innerText, 10) ? i : iMax, 0);      
  scores.forEach((score, i) => score.classList.add(winIndex == i ? 'win' : 'lose'));
});
```

But I did not contemplate the case of a draw and its solution is no more viable.

Any thoughts about how the logic would be in this new scenario ? `.win` / `.lose` / `.draw`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE #2**

Compare scores inside a `.war` item and apply classes to `.score` items

```js
function applyScoreClass() {
  $('.war').each(function(index, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var warScores = [];
    $elem.find('.score').each(function(i,el) {
       var txt = $(el).text();
       var num = (txt && txt.length > 0) ? parseInt(txt) : null;
       if (num !== null) {
           warScores.push({
               elem: $(el),
               score: num
           });
       }
    });
    if (warScores.length === 2) {
       if (warScores[0].score > warScores[1].score) {
           warScores[0].elem.addClass('win');
           warScores[1].elem.addClass('lose');
       } else if (warScores[0].score === warScores[1].score) {
           warScores[0].elem.addClass('draw');
           warScores[1].elem.addClass('draw');
       } else if (warScores[0].score < warScores[1].score) {
           warScores[1].elem.addClass('win');
           warScores[0].elem.addClass('lose');
       }
    }
  });
}

applyScoreClass();
```

```css
.war {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
.win {
  color: green;
}
.draw {
  color: orange;
}
.lose {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score">8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score">5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="war">
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score">2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span class="score">4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The idea as mencioned in the original question is to compare the first score with the second one. Scores can be 212 vs 159.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Nice one! Apreciate it :) Just saw you are applying classes to `war` `$elem.addClass('win');` instead of `score`, nearly !

Comment: Updated again applying classes to .score items

Answer (score 0):

Define id value for HTML div/span
inside looping scores array declare

```
var id =document.getElementById('spanId/divId');
id.classList.add('win/lose/draw');
```

Comment: The idea as mencioned in the original question is to iterate throw elements and not definining 80 score tags in the page. Your solution if I understand is puting `#score1, #score2, #score3, etc.`

Comment: I think based on array values ,that many div will be existed in HTML and then you can add class based on score value as condition.